# Enumerate through geometry objects in scene

Tags: python, scripting, geometry

If I just do:

```
for ob in context.scene.objects:
    print obj
```

I get:

```
<bpy_struct, Object("Cube")>
<bpy_struct, Object("Lamp")>
<bpy_struct, Object("Camera")>
```

How can I just get all of the objects that get drawn?  i.e. the ones with vertices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check for an objects '[type](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=object.type#bpy.types.Object.type)':

```
for ob in context.scene.objects:
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        print ob
```

Other 'types' include:

`CURVE`, `SURFACE`, `META`, `FONT`, `ARMATURE`, `LATTICE`, `EMPTY`, `CAMERA`, `LAMP`, `SPEAKER`.

If you want to check for multiple types you can used Python's set notion.

```
for ob in context.scene.objects:
    if ob.type in {'MESH', 'CURVE', 'SURFACE'}:
        print ob
```